# How do I convert this np.add.at statement to TensorFlow?

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

```
np.add.at(img, (slice(None), z, y, x), cols_reshaped)
```

`img` is 4d

`cols_reshaped` is 2d

`z`, `y`, `x` are all 2d

Comment: Can you express it as a loop?  That's what the numpy code is doing - in compiled code.  `img[...] += ...` does the same thing, except when there are duplicate indices.  It's the possibility of duplicates that prompted the writing of this `.at` method.

Comment: I'm looking for the TensorFlow equivalent. There is no direct equivalency, but there are workarounds such as SparseTensor and tf.scatter, but I haven't figured out how to convert the dimensions accurately.

Answer (score 0):

As of march 2018 Tensorflow is more limited than numpy when it comes to slicing operations and mutation. Tensorflow tensors are immutable (helps with differentiation), so you need to use variables if you want to mutate the variables. I think you can simulate this by chaining tf's strided_slice and strided_slice_assign functionality.